# Disable Plugin with one button

Tags: plugins, editor

After updating to 4.9, my Appearance editor becomes empty, and if one plugin has a problem, I need to disable all the plugin one by one which takes really long time and all I just need just update the logo. Do you or can you create a plugin enable and disable button. which can disable/not loading all plug in at once, and enable it again after the update. and if test any plugin and cause problem.

It will be very useful to bring the site up again.

Comment: You should be trying to figure out which specific plugin is causing your problem and resolving *that*.

Answer (score 1):

If you have FTP access (or File Manager on your hosting place), just rename the plugin's folder (in wp-content\plugins). That will deactivate the plugin, but won't remove the settings.

Once you fix things, you can put the plugin's folder name back to the original name. Then reactivate it.

(This is a great way to find an 'offending' plugin: just rename a plugins' folder name until the site is back to normal. )

Answer (score 1):

The FTP access / rename folder methods works and is handy if site very broken. However if you can still access the plugins list there is the bulk action way.  (Not one button, but close):

Tick the checkbox next to 'plugin' at the top of the plugins list. Then in 'bulk actions' just above, select 'Deactivate'.   All selected plugins will  deactivate and go into 'recently active' plugin list.

Then you can reactivate either one by one, or reactivate all by ticking the top checkbox again.